# Custom Variables in Jekyll Front Matter

Tags: jekyll

New to Jekyll and wondering if it's possible to include custom variables in Jekyll Front Matter. It would be useful for nested layouts, for example something like:

layouts/artist.html

```
----
layout: default
title: {{ page.artist }} (Artist)
----
```

I get an error trying that.

Comment: YAML (which is what the head matter is, Liquid doesn't perform substitutions there I don't think) supports [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#References) but I haven't been able to get them to work in a layout (they work locally in a page though).

Comment: I had a similar question where I needed pagination variables in the title.  A solution was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729309/599477

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, Jekyll do not support Liquid variables in the front matter, and the only way to do that would be through a plugin, such as **[jekyll-conrefifier](https://github.com/gjtorikian/jekyll-conrefifier)**.

---

Alternatively, what you can do, though, is create variables that you re-use *on the same file*:

```
{% assign new_title = page.title | append: " (Artist)" %}
<h1>{{ new_title }}</h1>
```

and you can also pass variables to files that get included. For example, including a file from `_includes\display-post.html` passing the modified title as an argument:

```
{% assign new_title = page.title | append: " (Artist)" %}
{% include display-post.html post_title=new_title %}
```

And then getting the value of the value passed in (example content of `_includes\display-post.html`):

```
{% assign title_received = include.post_title %}

<h1>Title that as passed in: {{ title_received }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this properly (i.e. server side), but a stop-gap measure could be to have a small snippet of Javascript that sets the correct title in the users browser. e.g.

```
---
title: Default title blah blah
---

[... content ...]

<span id="pagetitle" style="display: none">{{ page.artist | escape }} (Artist)</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pagetitle = document.getElementById("pagetitle");
    if (pagetitle) {
        document.title = pagetitle.textContent;
    }
</script>
```

#### Notes:

The substitution of `page.artist` is performed in HTML rather than in the Javascript because it is easier to quote any HTML special characters (via `escape`) rather than the Javascript special characters `'` or `"` or `\` (there isn't a built-in filter to do this).

One could also move the `pagetitle` span to the top of the page so that it is near the other YAML front matter.

Unfortunately, this is a very poor way of achieving this, but it looks like it might be the only way other than writing a plugin.

Comment: I ended up using this because I publish to GitHub Pages and GitHub Pages does not allow Jekyll plugins (except the ones [officially supported](https://pages.github.com/versions/)). So, the plugin solutions are not an option, but this one works.

Comment: This is not safe. This is a client side change via DOM manipulation and Google will see "Default title blah blah" which could hurt your SEO ranking