# jekyll blog title to include pagination variables

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to get Page 2+ of my blog to have a different title for search engines to index.

I have read several other stackoverflow answers stating that you cannot use liquid tags in the front matter yaml.  One suggested to use JS to update the title, however this will not work for me as I want the search engine to index the parsed title.

I thought there may be another way.  I can perhaps create a HTML page for each of my pages.  I would like to do that without having to manually add each one of my posts into each of the pages (resulting in an ongoing time consuming task each time I post a new article).

I was thinking I could make one page for 1-10, another page for 11-20, etc... Something like this:

```
---
title: Blog Page 2
---

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
{% if post.index > 10 %}{% if post.index <= 20 %}
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
        <h2 class="post-title"> {{ post.title }}</h2>
        {{ post.excerpt }}
    </a>
</div>
{% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It seems there is no post.index variable available.  Is there anything similar I can use?

Or are there any other ways to achieve "Blog Page X" in my title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that your head tags are in your _includes/head.html file. In the `title` tag just add :

```
{% if paginator %} - page {{ paginator.page }}{% endif %}
```

Your title tag now looks like this :

```
<title>
{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}
{%if paginator %} - page {{ paginator.page }}{% endif %}
</title>
```

Comment: What a great idea.  I actually feel kinda silly that I didn't think of that as a solution.  Thank you so much!