# Jekyll: link inside a variable called from a markdown file

Tags: markdown, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I have a series of posts in Jekyll for which I want to have a banner at the bottom with a link to an internal page.

Here's the beginning of my MD post:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Title"
date:   2022-12-06 18:26:05 +0100
categories: category
author: Author name
author-pic: author.jpg
banner-bottom: Some test some test some test [Link to a page]({{ site.baseurl | }}{% link page.html %}).
---
```

In the post layout I'm calling the variable `{{page.banner-bottom}}` inside a `<div>`:

```
{% include header.html %}

        <article>
            <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
            <div class="author-name">
                <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.author-pic }}" alt=""><span>{{ page.author }}</span>
            </div>

            {{content}}

            <div class="banner-bottom">{{page.banner-bottom}}</div>

    </article>

{% include footer.html %}
```

Unfortunately `[Link to a page]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link alumni.html %})` is rendered as text and not converted to a link. Any idea why? I also tried escaping site.baseurl like `{{ site.baseurl | escape }}` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO post: Custom Variables in Jekyll Front Matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218779/custom-variables-in-jekyll-front-matter) is somehow related but pretty old.

Here's an idea, actually not my own. I used the solution from this [blog post: How to nest template variables inside yaml front matter](http://acegik.net/blog/ruby/jekyll/plugins/howto-nest-liquid-template-variables-inside-yaml-front-matter-block.html) once.

The idea is simple:

#### 1. Create a plugin:

```
# file: _plugins/expand_nested_variable_filter.rb

module Jekyll
  module ExpandNestedVariableFilter
    def flatify(input)
      Liquid::Template.parse(input).render(@context)
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ExpandNestedVariableFilter)
```

#### 2. Apply the filter:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Title"
date:   2022-12-06 18:26:05 +0100
categories: category
author: Author name
author-pic: author.jpg
banner-bottom: Some test and [link to a page]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link page.html %}).
---

{{ site.baseurl | flatify }}
```

Jekyll searches links from the root folder, so you maybe need to adjust the path. Jekyll will tell you when your link is not valid :) I ended up testin g with my 404.html page